# Customise the system Exception instance to pass two parameters

Tags: c#, exception, parameter-passing

I need to customise the system exception without using the user defined exception classes.

Following is my requirement.

```
String ErrorMessage="";
Exception e= new Exception (ErrorMessage);
```

then I need to throw `errorMessage` string with one integer parameter for the upper layer in my project.

So can someone please let me know if I can customise the system Exception instance to pass two parameters (Integer value and `errorMessage` string)?

Comment: You can't.  All you can do is subclass it and add a new constructor that takes both parameters.

Comment: In all fairness, you *really shouldn't* be throwing `System.Exception`. This is basically just the grandfather of all managed exceptions, it should never be thrown directly, and almost never be handled. The **correct** way to do what you want is to subclass an existing exception and adding your properties and constructors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible.

Your only option is to create a new class that inherits from `System.Exception` or some other exception class and add whatever you need in there.

If you can't or won't do that, then you can't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Some real example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ExceptionExamples
{
    public static class Error
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class RegistryReadException : Exception
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Message template
            /// </summary>
            static string msg = "Can't parse value from Windows Registry.\nKey: {0}\nValue: {1}\nExpected type: {2}";

            /// <summary>
            /// Can't read value from registry
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="message"></param>
            public RegistryReadException(
                string message)
                : base(message) { }

            /// <summary>
            /// Can't read value from registry
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="key">Key path</param>
            /// <param name="value">Real value</param>
            /// <param name="type">Expected type</param>
            public RegistryReadException(
                string key, string value, Type type)
                : base( string.Format(msg, key, value, type.Name) ) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create some custom Exception classes and throw it using the same code TryCatch. But in the upper layer you can catch not by generic Exception, using your custom type.

```
Try
{
    //Your try code Here
    if(/*Something Happens*/)
    {
       throw new YourCustomExceptionClass("Message");
    }
    else
    {
       throw new AnotherCustomExceptionClass("Other Message");
    }
}
Catch(YourCustomExceptionClass err)
{
   //This will be a type of exception
}
Catch(AnotherCustomExceptionClass err)
{
   //This will be another type of Exception
}
```

Comment: The question *specifically* said he wasn't looking to create a new exception class.

Comment: I want to pass list or array of parameters using only c# system exception class. because I can not use the customise exception class due to some restriction in my projects.